# Mocking Hive with Mockito Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-test, flutter-hive

So basically, I want to check whether I've passed whatever I need to pass to the `HiveInterface` and `Box` when I want to store something.

`test.dart`:

```
group('cacheStoraygeUser', () {
    test(
      'should call HiveInterface and Box to cache data',
      () async {
        when(mockHiveInterface.openBox(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => mockBox);
        when(mockBox.put(0, tStoraygeUserModel))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => tStoraygeUserModel);
        // act
        dataSourceImpl.cacheStoraygeUser(tStoraygeUserModel);
        // assert
        verify(mockHiveInterface.openBox(STORAYGE_USER_BOX));
        verify(mockBox.put(STORAYGE_USER_ENTRY, tStoraygeUserModel));
      },
    );
  });
```

My implementation for `dataSourceImpl.cacheStoraygeUser()`:

```
@override
  Future<void> cacheStoraygeUser(
      StoraygeUserModel storaygeUserModelToCache) async {
    /// Precaution to ensure that [STORAYGE_USER_BOX] has been opened.
    ///
    /// If the box, is in fact not opened, Hive will just return the box since
    /// the box is a Singleton. I think.
    final box = await hiveInterface.openBox(STORAYGE_USER_BOX);
    box.put(STORAYGE_USER_ENTRY, storaygeUserModelToCache);
  }
```

When I try to run the test, it gives this error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<void>'
MockBox.put
package:hive/…/box/box_base.dart:80
```

I already generated the mock classes for `HiveInterface` and `Box`. I think this is how I should do it if I want to test Hive, since I can't seem to generate Mock classes for Hive itself. But if you know a better or the correct solution then please tell me.

I also wrote another test for getting stuff from Hive. This works perfectly fine.

```
test(
  'should return StoraygeUser from StoraygeUserBox when there is one in the cache',
  () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockHiveInterface.openBox(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => mockBox);
    when(mockBox.getAt(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => tStoraygeUserModel);
    // act
    final result = await dataSourceImpl.getCachedStoraygeUser();
    // assert
    verify(mockHiveInterface.openBox(any));
    verify(mockBox.getAt(any));
    expect(result, equals(tStoraygeUserModel));
  },
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe because you're not `await`ing in the first code?

Comment: I changed a bit to `await dataSourceImpl.cacheStoraygeUser(tStoraygeUserModel);` and the problem persists

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/412

Comment: where is `mockHiveInterface` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in Mockito 5.0.9

The problem stems from the fact that Box *implements* BoxBase rather than *extends* it.

Older versions of Mockito couldn't pick this up and thus, putAt and getAt and other methods are not generated in the mock classes.